# In Three Thousand Years of Longing, why does the Djinn try to lie to Alithea about something that just happened?

Tags: movie, character-motivation, magical-creatures, three-thousand-years-of-longing

It's difficult to ask this question about [Three Thousand Years of Longing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three_Thousand_Years_of_Longing) without spoiling anything, but hopefully I kept the title vague enough for this purpose. Here's my question:

> Near the end of the movie, when Alithea comes back home, she discovers the Djinn almost "fossilized" and turning to ashes,
>  unable to speak. So she wishes he could speak, which reverses the process,  and makes him able to move again.
>  However, he immediately lies to her by saying he was in fact
>  sleeping (contradicting one of his earlier statements when he told Alithea that Djinns do not sleep, as she remarks).
>  My guess is that he lies because he loves her and doesn't want her to "waste" another wish on him (as for example, she could wish that he was able to stay in the human world indefinitely without any trouble).
>  However, I could be mistaken, and there might be another explanation
>  that I entirely missed.

So, why his immediate, spontaneous reaction was to lie? Is there some stated or implied reason for that?

I didn't read the short story from which the movie has been adapted, but if it has some explanation about it, I'm interested too.

Comment: In my opinion, he lies because telling Alithea that he can't stay in the mortal world implies being separated from her, and the Djinn is in love with her.